# flutter test enterText on widget extending EditableText "Bad state: No element" : building editable text for mention

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, mention

I have a class that extends EditableText, which provides styled editing - colour spans and so on.

The parent widget has a bool flag to use default TextInput or the custom one that extends EditableText.

Testing works fine for the default one:

```
final String dummyDesc = 'dummy desc';
final Finder mention = find.byType(Mention);
await tester.enterText(mention, dummyDesc);
```

however, if I do the same on a page where Mention uses the custom input, the test fails as it cannot find a TextInput - as there isn't one.

Error:

`Bad state: No element`

How Do you use enterText on a widget that extends EditableText? Or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be due to the `showKeyboard` method that `enterText` calls internally: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3b067049adc14ffb300e78d9b0d0adf3d581de7c/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart#L854

It is checking that the finder matches or is a descendent of `EditableText`, which does it's matching based on the runtimeType.

It's a bit hacky, but you could provide a runtimeType getter, which returns `EditableText` and will allow it to work.

```
class Mention extends EditableText {
  // ...

  Type get runtimeType => EditableText;

  // ...
}
```

Caveat: This will mean that you will not be able to `find.byType(Mention)` any more. You can work around this by writing a custom finder, or using the predicate finder `find.byElementPredicate((Element element) => element.widget is Mention)`.